# Tab files into pandas dataframe according to columns with missing headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I turn a tab file, with empty columns headers, into a dataframe?  More specifically, how can I fill this dataframe only with values that correspond with a letter in the adjacent unlabeled column, in this case 'P'?

This is a representation of the tab file I'm using.  Note the lack of headers over the A or P columns.

```
gene   cell_1      cell_2  
MYC    5.0     P   4.0     A
AKT    3.0     A   1.0     P
```

The desired dataframe would look like this:

```
gene   cell_1   cell_2  
MYC    5.0      NaN
AKT    NaN      1.0
```

What is the best way to tackle this problem using pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to implement a few different approaches that show fancy indexing and masking methods. Let me know if you have any questions

```
#Load Data
string_data = "gene cell_1  cell_2 \nMYC 5.0 P 4.0 A\nAKT 3.0 A 1.0 P"
A_pre = np.array([row.split(" ") for row in string_data.split("\n")])
DF_data = pd.DataFrame(A_pre[1:,1:],
                       index=pd.Series(A_pre[1:,0],name=A_pre[0,0]),
                       columns=A_pre[0,1:])

A_data = DF_data.as_matrix() #Set the data array b/c it's quicker to slice than DF
rowLabels, colLabels = DF_data.index, DF_data.columns

# #Get blank columns
gene_idx = np.where(np.array(colLabels) != "")[0] #Used later
numColBlank = len(colLabels) - len(gene_idx)

# #Placeholder to fill
DF_placeholder = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((DF_data.shape[0],DF_data.shape[1] - numColBlank)),
                              index = DF_data.index,
                              columns = DF_data.columns[gene_idx]
                              )
DF_data

#Populate matrix
query = "P"
for i in range(DF_data.shape[0]):
    for j in range(DF_data.shape[1]):
        if colLabels[j] == "":
            if A_data[i,j] == query:
                cell = colLabels[j-1]
                gene = rowLabels[i]
                metric = A_data[i,j-1]
                DF_placeholder.loc[gene,cell] = metric

#I just found out about masks they are useful
mask = DF_placeholder == 0.0
DF_placeholder[mask] = np.nan
DF_processed = DF_placeholder
DF_processed
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For your example data, `pandas`'s `read_fwf()` function (for "fixed-width format") does a good job of guessing the columns:

```
s = """gene   cell_1      cell_2  
MYC    5.0     P   4.0     A
AKT    3.0     A   1.0     P"""

import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
in_file = StringIO(s)

pd.read_fwf(in_file)
Out[6]: 
  gene  cell_1 Unnamed: 2  cell_2 Unnamed: 4
0  MYC     5.0          P     4.0          A
1  AKT     3.0          A     1.0          P
```

Comment: This is a great start! Then if I wanted to create the desired DF, how could I keep only the adjacent "P" values and turn the "A" values into Nan?  That part is still confusing...

Answer (score 1):

```
# Read the dataframe.
filename = '...'
df = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=1, header=None, sep=" ", skipinitialspace=True)
df = df.rename(columns={0: 'gene', 1: 'cell_1', 2:'a_p', 3: 'cell_2', 4: 'p_a'})

# Changes adjacent 'A' values to NaN.
df.loc[df.a_p == 'P', 'cell_2'] = None
df.loc[df.p_a == 'P', 'cell_1'] = None

>>> df[['gene', 'cell_1', 'cell_2']]
  gene  cell_1  cell_2
0  MYC       5     NaN
1  AKT     NaN       1
```