# Check if process is hanging in Jupyter iPython notebook

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

The process I'm running in a iPython notebook continues to run past an hour.  The process is a manipulation of a large dataframe, 6400col x 200000rows, explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36586672/4154548).  It appears the cell is still running `In:[*]`, but I want to know if its hanging vs being productive.  Inserting print statements only worked to a point (possibly due to some limit of print statements in iPython).

I'm using Python 3.5.1 and IPython 4.1.2 from Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit).

Comment: If you have a loop, you can print every nth step with a check like `if i % 1000 == 0`.  If it's some long running operation deeper than your code, there's no easy way to distinguish between hanging and being productive.

Comment: I had similar issues for webscraping and experienced limited success with the `if i %....` printing statement.
My workaround was to  break down the steps into parts of an iteration loop and include print statements for each step of the loop, which worked fine. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

One check is to launch a terminal from your Jupyter Home and run top or other such command to see the running processes and their utilization.  Pair this with some sort of print statement(s) and you can catch many hangs or other issues.

Comment: Problem is that it shows the Jupyter kernel running whether or not a cell is being executed/run

Comment: @ThomasMatthew Yes, but what are the CPU usage and other stats at?  Top won't catch all hangs but it gives you more information on what is going on.  For example, if you see the CPU% staying pegged then you have some idea that whatever its doing (just taking a while to finish or getting caught in a loop) its not getting dead ended.  You can also watch memory utilization to see how that's responding the longer it runs.

Answer (score 1):

Use the tools that your operating system provides to check the CPU usage. If one of your CPU's is pegged, it's running. Otherwise it's probably hanging.